# Initialize the Google / Admob Mobile Ads SDK vs Firebase SDK

Tags: android, firebase, admob, firebase-admob

I'm using Firebase SDK for google ads. I can see there is a difference of initializing Mobile Ads SDK between [firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#add-and-initialize-sdk) and [AdMob SDK.](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) in their doc.

Firebase:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 // ...
 MobileAds.initialize(this);
}
```

Admob:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
```

Which should I use? Although both of them are working.

Comment: `MobileAds.initialize()` can optionally take the `OnInitializationCompleteListener` listener. If you need to observe the init status, you can implement that, else simply use `MobileAds.initialize(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

The only different between both of them is callback
Let assume you only want to start requesting the ads (banner,intersial...)
when the Connection with admob is created in this scenario you need

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
//loadbanner();
            }
        });
```

but if you are not concerned about listening to  admob initialisation then use

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this);
```